# Groovy/Grails how to make constructor private - the right way

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a domain class in grails that should only be created once with the same name. To ensure that I have a static method getColor and private constructors that looks as follows:

```
class Color {
  String name

  static hasMany = [moods: Mood] 

  // not accessible
  private Color() {}

  // not accessible because getColor should be used
  private Color(String name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  static getColor(String name) {
    def color = Color.findByName(name.toLowerCase())
    color ? color : new Color(name).save(flush:true) 
  }

  def beforeValidate() {
    name = name.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

to ensure that object of Color are only created by using the static getColor method I wanted to make the constructor private. It works so far, that I can create objects of Color. But when I use this instances to create an object of Object Mood

```
class Mood {

  static belongsTo = [color:Color]

}

def color = Color.getColor('verylightgreen')
def mood = new Mood(color: color)
```

I get an exception:

```
error initializing the application: Could not instantiate bean class [de.tobi.app.Color]: Is the constructor accessible?
```

This exception is thrown by

```
def mood = new Mood(color: color)
```

So why does creation of Mood need access to the constructor of Color. I already passed the object..
And in general, whats the best way in groovy/grails to hide the contructor of a domain class to controll how objects are created. Especially the usage of the map controller should be disabled too.

Comment: why don't you use Enums for this kind of thing?

Comment: because the user should be able to dynamically add new objects

Comment: I think you should look into having uniqueness enforced through database constraints.

Comment: yes thought about it too and i think it would be an alternative.. but still i think as it is a wide spread programming pattern to wanna have controll about object creation in some cases it should be possible in groovy too

Comment: What is holding you back making `name` the primary key? And How is `Color` associated to `Mood`?

Comment: well yea like i said making name being unique with a constraint would be an alternative in this case. But this question is meant more general, how can i have controll about the creation of the object?
And you're right, forgot the Color-Mood relation. it is hasMany. I will edit it in my post

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Grails will replace the default constructor for domain classes, so I think it's not a good idea to create private constructors. You can enforce uniqueness with a database constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding the exception:**

The exception is occurring due to the map constructor. With normal groovy classes, this is not an issue, but grails registers domain classes as prototype beans. It then overrides the constructor in the metaclass to use the bean creation and autowiring mechanism to get an instance. Something in the map constructor and auto-wiring is causing an empty color bean to be created prior to being set by the map.

If you change the code to:

```
Color c = Color.getColor('red')
Mood m = new Mood()
m.color = c
m.save()
```

The exception should disappear.

You may consider filing a [JIRA issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS) for this particular use case, but I don't know whether or not the grails team would consider this a bug or a design decision. It is certainly not documented anywhere.

**Regarding the design:**

Without knowing much more about your model, I agree with dmahapatro about shifting the responsibility for data integrity onto your database and GORM constraints. That's what they're for.

Circumventing this causes unusual use patterns in the code such as knowing to use `Color.getColor` as opposed to normal domain class instantiation.

The ideology behind a convention over configuration framework like Grails is to adhere to the conventions as much as possible, such that anyone familiar with the conventions can step in and know immediately what is going on.

Answer (score 5):

Using `name` as the primary key for `Color` you can achieve uniqueness. Plus, [findOrSaveBy*](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrSaveBy.html) can be used to replace the custom static method `getColor`.

If making `name` a primary key is not a viable option, then you can go ahead with adding a constraint as mentioned by almost all of the individuals in comments to the question. :)

```
class Color {
  String name

  static mapping = {
      //column is optional
      id name: 'name', generator: 'assigned', type: 'string', column: 'NAME' 
  }

  static hasMany = [moods : Mood] //for example

  //DO NOT NEED THIS
  //This can be achieved by findOrSaveBy*
  /*static getColor(String name) {
    def color = Color.findByName(name.toLowerCase())
    color ? color : new Color(name).save(flush:true) 
  }*/

  def beforeValidate() {
    name = name.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Then you can very well do

```
def color = Color.findOrSaveByName('verylightgreen')
def mood = new Mood()

color.addToMoods(mood)
color.save()
```

Comment: so its a good way to make it in this case.. but does that mean that you in grails simply dont make your domain class constructor private?

Comment: @tobi Never used or thought of it as I get that flexibility using mappings and constraints block.

Comment: @SérgioMichels Buddy, GORM has been the Ray Ban glass for a long time, it depends on the developer who wears it. ;) .Think of Ratpack, plan is to have some thing like GORM in it. I would be the happiest developer to see something like GORM in Node.js or find something like it when I use it. :)

Comment: @tobi Was the answer helpful? Accept an answer whichever you feel is appropriate to accept.

Comment: is there any practical difference in this case in writing
static mapping = {id name 'name'} and just making name unique?
written like that: static contraints = { name blank:false, unique:true}

Comment: @tobi Yes. Since name in the former case is a primary key, uniqueness is forced by default. In the later case, every time you do any CRUD operation, the `constraints` for the domain class kicks off to fire the validation. Either case is good, but you get more flexibility in the later case if you do not want to use an assigned primary key but ask hibernate to take care of the `id` and have `name` as another field. :-)

Comment: thx for the answer. so i guess making the name field an id would speed up CRUD operations if i have many many objects of Color. An alternative would be using an indexColumn. Would you prefer something?